# Sticky Tooltips that show on click and hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a solution to allow a double behavior on click and on mouseover. Esentially, I need to display a div when hovering over an image but also to pin it (display it until another event) on the page and hide it if the user clicks outside of it / outside of the image.

This is what I have so far

**HTML**
        
        Hiya

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#garden-1").mouseover(function(e) {
    //  Show my popup with slide effect, this can be a simple 
    $("#garden1").show("slow");

  // Bind click event to a link
  $("#garden-1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //  Show my popup with slide effect, this can be a simple .show() or .fadeToggle()
    $("#garden1").slideToggle("slow");
  });

  // Cancel the mouseup event in the popup
  $("#garden1").mouseup(function() {
    return false
  });
  // Bind mouseup event to all the document
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    // Check if the click is outside the popup
    if($(e.target).parents("#garden1").length==0 && !$(e.target).is("#garden1")) {
      // Hide the popup
      $("#garden1").slideUp("slow");
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

However, the result is less than idea as you can see here: http://candelascommunity.businesscatalyst.com/test

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The larger problem though is that you should just contain each instance, and make it smoother and easier.

If you were to change your html to be more like.

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="/img/palm.jpg"/>
    <p>Hiya</p>
</div>
```

and your jquery to be more like

```
$('.box img').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings('p').show();
}, function() {
    if (!$(this).siblings('p').hasClass('on')) {
        $(this).siblings('p').hide();
    }
}).on('click', function(){
    $('.on').removeClass('on').hide();
    $(this).siblings('p').addClass('on');
});
```

then you would just need to add this css, and you should be set

```
.box p{display:none}
.box p.on{display:block!important}
```

Made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/NqQFh/

Comment: Actually, the image is #garden1 and the text (tooltip) is #garden-1 (didn't port well on the post).
I need them to be different (by ID not by class) because there are multiple tooltips showing.

Comment: yes, this is very very close. Thanks! I just need for the item to also close if I click outside the items.

Comment: updated it to not be dependent on images, so you could also use an image sprite to make the backgrounds for all of them, but the images will still work. http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/NqQFh/